# Getting a object from AWS S3 using "getObjectCommand" from @aws-sdk/client-s3 in react-native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

Trying to get a object from S3 using @aws-sdk/client-s3 in react-native. The response Body of sending "getObjectCommand" is of type stream and react-native has not support for streams,it complains that stream is a Node library.
I am a begginer, can someone tell me how to overcome this problem.

I tried to get a object from S3, but response is a stream and I fail to consume a stream in react-native.
I prefer not to use AWS Amplify becouse all other parts of project are done using aws sdk.

Comment: What do you want to do with the streamed object? And is this iOS or Android?